# VSC: NuGet only making C# files available for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to make it available for Python? All project files are in the same directory.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSspy.png)

I added NuGet and expected it to work with Python. It installed Selenium.Webdriver 4.11.0 successfully but I'm still getting errors for my Python file.

Comment: The selenium package on NuGet provides bindings for .NET. You need to install the Python bindings for selenium using `pip install selenium`.

Comment: I've already installed Selenium along with its respective webdriver. It works in terminals but not in VSC.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I am. I see selenium in my VE's pip list.

Comment: If you click "3.8.2 64 bit" in the bottom right corner it should bring up a list of python interpreters. Choose the interpreter for your virtual env.

Comment: 3.8.2 is the correct one. It's the only one I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is usually caused by not selecting the correct Python interpreter.
The bottom right corner displays `3.8.2`. If you have chosen the virtual environment, it will display more information.

Directly using the installed Python environment:

[image]

conda environment:

[image]

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose your virtual environment Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. I was able to create the environment but still can't enable selenium for python after selecting the venv interpreter. Still troubleshooting.